# Type of a child class of an abstract parent with a static factory

Tags: typescript

I want to refer to the type of a class that extends an abstract class and has a static factory function that is implement in its abstract parent.

I learnt how to write static factories in abstract classes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65717206/923846.

Please consider this code:

```
abstract class Parent {
    public static factory<T extends Parent>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T) {
        return new this();
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent { }
class Child2 extends Parent { }

// what specific type can i use instead of "any" here:
const arr: any[] = [ Child1, Child2 ];

let child1 = arr[0].factory();
let child2 = arr[1].factory();
```

I used the `any` type of the elements in `arr`.

I would like to use a specific type.

I tried to declare it like this:

```
type TParent = typeof Parent;

...

const arr: TParent[] = [ Child1, Child2 ];

...

// i get an error for this line:
let child1 = arr[0].factory();
```

I get the error "Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type".

So how to declare this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it would be the easiest to let typescript infer the types and using `as const` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4BQC5CADgK4jICWsCkwEjCAZnBAPZQCeAHgAqCXAA8IBACYZseQgD4AFBAAW9MAC4E%20XAHcEygHSmcAc20Jg%20fgG0AugEoEAXkUJhL0hV8I8ENRQ%20LoGCOqayk4A3GQUAL4kiSQoaBgAwhrI0gCMYpIycjgExAhx0jwAyjwAtrgR%20OZRRImJqegImfTZAEz5UviyWMWECD4IFdV1DeYAIvQcHLgKEM2tJCk8%20JDWUFBuCHadWbkANMfd0n0O1hiwW5CxJMj1SCd5rrtQdgAMDsZceB8fhRWIvRCwE59T44b45f6A3gCUFAA)):

```
const arr = [ Child1, Child2 ] as const;

let child1 = arr[0].factory(); // type Child1
let child2 = arr[1].factory(); // type Child2
```

For a generic type we would need to get rid of the `abstract constructor`-type and change it to a normal one to be able to instantiate via `new this()` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4BQC5CADgK4jICWsCkwEjCAZnBAPZQCeAHgAqCXAA8IBACYZseQgD4AFBAAW9MAC4E%20XAHcEygHSmcAc20Jg%20fgG0AugEoEAXkUJhL0hV8I8ENRQ%20LoGCOqayk4A3GQUAL4kiSQoaBgAwhrI0gCMYpIycjgExAhx0jwAyjwAtrgR%20OZRRImJqegImfTZAEz5UviyWMWECD4IFdV1DeYAIvQcHLgKEM2tJCQA9JtIPPgAbsuI6rjW4NDcu-iQUNTwfOE81rp8NcDICHunNtLW0r8nZgQVjsDjUfDweh7DD7ejAcL8Si4HgcYYrEgQRGneQlSq0dKoDquMZ6fRRBA6HGEeIIABkRkxSJRaJKMQ2sGhiBwUEpIwgeJABLSjjcCDsnSyuQANBLutI%20g5YiRkPUkJK8sTuXYAAwOYxce4CKKxFWIWCSvqaqBQOw5PUG3hGmJAA)):

```
// convert the abstract constructor to a normal one and add the static functions via typeof Parent
type ParentSubClass = {new() : Parent} & (typeof Parent);

const arr: ParentSubClass[] = [ Child1, Child2 ];

let child1 = arr[0].factory(); // type Parent
let child2 = arr[1].factory(); // type Parent
```